# Equilibrium in Gas Phase and Pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

In one task/example there is gas phase reaction and it is said that reaction takes place at pressure of 1 bar and standard Gibbs energy of reaction is needed to be calculated. In this task 1 bar is meant to be equilibrium pressure of a mixture. Problem I have is that total pressure initially is less than 1 bar since number of moles is increasing in reaction, but if so why do we calculate standard reaction Gibbs energy since such quantity is applicable for predicting equilibrium conditions at constant pressure? How can standard reaction Gibbs energy predict equilibrium state if pressure during reaction is changed?

Comment: Didn't you just say that reaction takes place at pressure of 1 bar? This typically means that the pressure was 1 bar both before **and** after the reaction. The changing number of moles is irrelevant.

Comment: Number of moles of gas being changed doesn't necessarily mean pressure is being changed.  If the container were at constant V, then, yes, p would have to change. But if you are conducting the experiment in an open container (a typical scenario), the pressure is always going to be determined by the ambient pressure (i.e., the pressure in your lab), which will remain constant at about 1 bar (assuming your lab is at about sea level).

Comment: Actually, this is not the case. While at equilibrium pressure is 1 bar, I needed to calculate what was initial pressure of reactant because I need to calculate equilibrium constant (Kp). After doing famous analysis in equilibrium tasks: initial, change and equilibrium, what I've gotten is that initial pressure of a reaction mixture is lower than equilibrium one.

Comment: @theorist, yes I agree with you. But, in this task after doing famous analysis in equilibrium tasks: initial, change and equilibrium, what I've gotten is that initial pressure of a reaction mixture is lower than equilibrium one.

Comment: If that happened, then the reaction by definition wasn't being conducted at constant pressure. (Of course *real* reactions are *not* conducted at exactly constant pressure, but a typical open container in a lab that isn't, say, exploding will keep its pressure close to the ambient pressure.)

Comment: @Ian Well, if this is so (and I agree with you), how can standard reaction Gibbs energy predict equilibrium condition since in the task I am asked to calculate it?

Comment: You're asked to calculate what? The Gibbs energy change? Or the equilibrium pressure? The equilibrium pressure is just the pressure that the reaction is held at from outside (to within this approximation). Under that condition (and constant temperature also), you can define and calculate the Gibbs energy change.

Comment: Standard reaction Gibbs energy from equilibrium constant (Kp) through famous expression, deltaG(standard) = -RTln(K). Equilibrium pressure of a mixture is needed along with dissociation degree to calculate partial pressures initially and in equilibrium since I need these to calculate Kp.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the experimental design that this computation is meant to serve. Is it a gas phase reaction in a sealed container whose pressure is held fixed by a mobile piston?

Comment: @ Ian, you didn't, I didn't explain the task in detail. So, there is a dissociaton of N2O4 to 2NO2. What you asked is  reaction happening in a sealed container with mobile piston isn't specified. Equilibrium pressure (1 bar) and degree of dissociation of N2O4 are given. Standard reaction Gibbs energy is needed to be calculated. To do so we need Kp, for which we need partial pressures at equilibrium. To find equilibrium pressures we need to do standard initial, change and equilibrium analysis (Do you know what I mean?).

Comment: After you do this analysis, it turns out that pressure of reaction mixture in beggining (when you have only N2O4)  is not the same as equilibrium. If so, why do we calculate standard reaction Gibbs energy since it isn't applicable to predict equilibrium in these conditions? We can use this quantity to predict equilibrium if this reaction is carried at 1 bar from start to equilibrium which isn't the case in our task. So, as you said, we need to increase the volume of our system to keep the system at constant pressure since number of moles is increasing.

Comment: If the system is actually held at constant pressure, such as by conducting the reaction in a sealed container with a mobile piston with a fixed external pressure on the piston, then Gibbs energy calculations can be used to predict equilibrium conditions. This also *approximately* works if, say, the reaction is in a sealed container and the total pressure of the reactants/products is much less than the fixed pressure from the other gas in the container.

Comment: @ Ian, yes. In this example, volume was probably held constant since pressure is changing, but I was still asked to find Gibbs energy since I can use it to predict equilibrium, but in conditions of constant pressure at equilibrium, not in conditions of a task.

Comment: You can compare the actual values of the Gibbs energy as a state function regardless of anything, though again in order to use this to predict equilibrium conditions, you need to impose external pressure and external temperature control on the system. I still think you are most likely misunderstanding something about the situation being modeled.

Comment: As I said, task doesn't specify any kind of conditions that you asked me like is it sealed container or does it have mobile piston. Given the equilibrium pressure of a mixture and dissociation degree for specific reaction, calculate Kp and standard deltaG at 298 K. That is all.

Comment: OK, then if you want to justify why you would do such a calculation you can imagine a mobile piston scenario where the volume of the system increases as you run the reaction so that constant pressure is maintained. As for actually doing the calculation, the partial pressures are just modeled as the associated mole fractions of each gas in the system times the total pressure.

Comment: You wrote: "While at equilibrium pressure is 1 bar, I needed to calculate what was initial pressure of reactant because I need to calculate equilibrium constant (Kp)."  Based on this, I think you are confusing the total pressure (1 bar) with the partial pressures of the individual chemicals involved the reaction.  The partial pressures of the individual chemicals will change, of course, as the reaction proceeds.  But if the reaction is in an open container, the total pressure at the end will be the same as the total pressure at the start, since that's just the ambient pressure.

Comment: Yes, I figured everything out as I was talking with others here. Thank you.